# Scaldi - default binding with override

Tags: scala, scaldi

I would like to inject two different instances of my database wrapper class (DB): a default instance and a readonly instance.

99% of usages of the class use the default instance. I would therefore like to be able to use the simple `inject[DB]` to get the default instance.

For the readonly instance, I'd like to supply an override: `inject[DB] identifiedBy  'readonly`

I have setup my bindings as follows:

```
  bind[misc.DB] identifiedBy 'readonly to new misc.DB(..readonly params)
  bind[misc.DB] to new misc.DB(...readwrite params)
```

However, injecting the DB with the `'readonly` identifier yields the readwrite instance. Is there any way to get this setup to work without having to supply an identifier for my default instance?

Comment: As an update to this, it looks like even if I supply an identifier for both bindings, the last defined binding always takes precedence (identifier used in the injector is completely ignored)

Comment: Do you still have that issue? what version was that? We're doing the same and `inject[DB]('readonly)` is working fine for us.